# ¿Como puedo cambiar la fecha por App Script?

Tags: javascript, java, script, app

Se me está presentando un problema con las fechas. Estoy enviando unos datos los cuales contienen fechas por medio de app script, pero los datos de las celdas con formato de fecha no me los reconoce en el envío, solo me reconoce los que tienen formato de texto.

Necesito que me lea el formato de fecha o en su defecto cualquier tipo de formato... Muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Te recomiendo esta libreria: https://date-fns.org/

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido, Hola XX, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!